# Событие на элементе с внутренностями

Tags: события, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, поправить скрипт и понять почему в настоящем виде он работает в ff и не работает в chrome

```
if (e.target.tagName == 'ARTICLE') {
    e.target.style = 'background: red';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DYsEg/

Хотелось бы, чтобы при клике по любому элементу, вложенному в `article` (например по p, по `span`, по `div`) происходила бы замена бэкграунда `article` на красный

Проблема сейчас в том, что пользователь фактически может кликнуть или по span, или по p, или ещё по другому элементу. смена бэкграунда при этом не происходит. иногда непосредственно - по `article`, в этом случае происходит. но это не есть хорошо

Comment: Зачем вам велосипед? все придумано до нас [вариант с jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/DYsEg/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function lookUpElement(child, parentNodeName, stopAt) {
    if(stopAt && stopAt == child) return null;
    if (child.tagName == parentNodeName) return child;

    return child.parentNode ? lookUpElement(child.parentNode, parentNodeName, stopAt) : null;
}

document.getElementById('tabContainer').addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    var article = lookUpElement(e.target, 'ARTICLE', this);
    article.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

}, false);
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/DYsEg/10/

Answer (score 4):

А кто сказал что с объектом [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) так обращаться можно ?

Надо

```
 e.target.style.background='red';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DYsEg/2/

Comment: @eicto: это сопутствующая ошибка, ее исправление не решает заданный вопрос.

Comment: в  хроме решает :) в опере не работает, поэтому вам плюс поставил

Comment: @Павел Азанов у вас тоже не все гладко :) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DYsEg/6/

Comment: @eicto: Спасибо, исправил. Ваш код работает если попасть точно в article, что крайне сложно. Как это решить, @Sergey Kalinin и пытался спросить.

Comment: ну ошибка и там и там была, что существеннее трудно сказать. кстати зачем вы делаете `var c=` и потом его передаете вместо this ? [типа так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DYsEg/9/)

Comment: @eicto: да, можно просто передать this, сразу не подумал, пора спать уже) утром поправлю.